# Creating 7 Fields from timestamp (One for each day)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table of data with a timestamp field.

For the analysis that I am working on I need to create a table that is 7 fields wide and 24 records down: 7 days of the week and 24 hours of the day.

The goal is to look at a particular event by hour of week.

With my current level of knowledge in SQL I was going to attempt something like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM THE_TIMESTAMP_FIELD) = 1, EXTRACT(DAY FROM THE_TIMESTAMP_FIELD) = 2, etc
```

But:

1. I'm using Teradata and datepart() or datename() do not seem to work (For the day name e.g. Mon, Tue, wed etc)
2. The `SELECT` statement example above will produce day of the month (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc).

Is there a better way to `SELECT` each day of the week, rather than manually typing a `EXTRACT` statement for each day 1:7?

How would I even extract the dayname in teradata?

Comment: What's your TD release?

Comment: "Teradata Client 14.10"? That what you were after?

Comment: That's the client, the DBMS might be lower, what's returned by `select * from dbc.dbcinfoV;`?

Comment: Ah,
VERSION 12.00.03.25a
LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE Standard
RELEASE 12.00.03.21

Comment: Ouch, that's quite old, but still possible. I'll give it a try :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a kind of PIVOT query, which is unfortunately not supported in TD.

But it's possible, looks like a lot of source code, but it's mainly cut & paste & modify.

Assuming a table `tab` with a timestamp column `ts`and you want to average column `col`:

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) as "hour"
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'mon' THEN col END) AS mon
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'tue' THEN col END) AS tue
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'wed' THEN col END) AS wed
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'thu' THEN col END) AS thu
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'fri' THEN col END) AS fri
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'sat' THEN col END) AS sat
  ,AVG(CASE WHEN ts (FORMAT 'eee') (CHAR(3)) = 'sun' THEN col END) AS sun
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Btw, `EXTRACT(DAY...)` doesn't return the day of week, it's the day of month, i.e. 1..31

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth. That worked. For my piece of mind: what is format 'eee' doing?
Why grouped and ordered by 1?

Comment: It returns the first three characters of the english weekday, e.g. 'wed' for today, 'eeee' gives the full weekday = 'wednesday'